# Page source not loading in case of http redirection

Tags: java, facebook, selenium-webdriver

I am doing  automation for a facebook app.

First I opened a url, that opened a popup. So I thought there is a iframe popup and then I tried to use driver.switchTo().frame() but not switched to the frame.

After going through the html and java script code, i found that it is redirecting to another page, there available the iframe to be switched.

but the problem is page source of the redirected url is not loading

How do I switch to iframe in case the page source where iframe available is not loading?